# MOV attack when $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is cyclic

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

Suppose $P\in E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ and $R=dP$.

In the MOV attack, we compute $\alpha=e(P,T)$ and $\beta=e(R,T)$ and try to solve the discrete logarithm problem for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ where $k$ is the embedding degree.

But if $E(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is cyclic (which it can be even in the supersingular case), $\alpha,\beta$ are doomed to be $1$.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Why are they doomed to be 1? You would have $\alpha=\beta=1_{T}$ iff. $P=R=G_{1}$ and $T=G_2$, where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are the generators of the first group and second group respectively, which I suppose, is not the case. In the target group you have that $\beta=d\alpha$. Thus we have reduced the discrete logarithm problem on the group of points on an elliptic curve to the discrete logarithm on finite fields, where subexponential attacks are known.

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of the MOV attack you choose $T$ to be a point in $E(\mathbb{F}_{q^k})$.